# How do you search through one work in TLG?

Tags: greek, research

The [Thesaurus Linguae Graecae (TLG)](http://stephanus.tlg.uci.edu/) is a popular research tool for working on Greek texts. (Unfortunately, it's a "freemium" model, so you need to pay for full access or get it through a research institution.)

I am trying to do something that--you'd think--is quite easy: searching for all occurrences of a given word/lemma in a given work. Specifically, I am looking for all occurrences of "τέλος" in Aristotle's *Politics*.

The TLG offers a simple way to narrow the results to a given *author*, but I'm struggling to reduce them to a given *work* of that author.

Right now, I can only think of two ways to do this, after reducing the results to "Aristotle":

- Do a lemma search, and (taking advantage of the default sorting by work) find the page where that work begins. (Not fun!)
- In the right-hand menu ("My search selection"), deselect one-by-one all the works except the one you want to search. (Very time-consuming!)

Am I missing an obvious feature that allows this kind of filtering to occur?

Comment: @AlexB For what it's worth, I do have access to the institutional version of TLG (and Loeb). Do you happen to know if the Loeb includes correct references to Bekker numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a way to do this for the letter to First Corinthians and will share it here because this seems to be the first hit for people struggling with the TLG.

I went first to the "Browser" tab and filtered my work there. For me, that was typing in Novum Testamentum and then selecting Ad Corinthios. When I did it for yours, I had to type in Aristoteles and then select Politica from the list presented to me. Once I had the Politics open, I clicked on the "Search This Text" in the upper left-hand corner. See the screen-shot below for the Search This Text.[image]

I then saved it as a bookmark so that I wouldn't have to go through this rigmarole every time.